# R: append column in a dataframe with frequency count based on two columns

Tags: r, data-structures, dplyr

I have a dataset like that:

```
name  height 
John    188
John    190
Jack    182
Jack    174
Jack    174
```

And I need to append a column with the frequency count based on both (name) and (height), without modifying the structure of my dataset, e.g. like so:

```
name  height occurrence
John    188      1
John    190      1
Jack    182      1
Jack    174      2
Jack    174      2
```

Is there a one liner to do so? I've looked around but don't seem to find an answer to that.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `data.table` you can use (Thanks @David Arenburg for the improvement)

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, occurrence := .N, by = .(name, height)]
```

My original answer (which copies the data insted of adding it by reference via `:=`)

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,rep(.N,.N),.(name, height)]
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Excellent, thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(name,height) %>% 
   mutate(new = n()) %>% 
   data.frame()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `base R` `ave` function like

```
ave(1:nrow(df), paste(df$name, df$height), FUN = length)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2
```